# Create nested object in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, reactjs, object

I want to create a nested object in javascript as following.

```
const data = {
  name: 'Context 1',
  children: [
    {
      name: 'Option 1',
      children: [
        {
          name: 'Context',
          children: [
            {
              name: 'Option'
            },
             {
               name: 'Option'
             }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: 'Option 2',
      children: [
        {
          name: 'Context 1',
          children: [
            {
              name: 'Option'
            },
            {
              name: 'Option'
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The object starting from `Context 1`, each 'Context' will have 2 or 3 `options` and every `option` will have one `Context` and that `Context` can again have 2/3 `options` and so on.

> The user will have control to define upto which level are we going to extend the object.

> By level, its defined like this
> [image]

I tried something like this with **ReactJs** but it didn't work.

State:

```
this.state = {
   myContentIndex: 1,
   myLevelIndex: 0,
   levels: 3,
}
```

My functions:

Here I called `addContext([], 3)`

```
addContext = async (data, options) => {
  const myData = [...data]
  const { myContextIndex, myLevelIndex, levels } = this.state
  await myData.push(this.getDataNodeObject('Context', myContextIndex))
  this.setState({ myContextIndex: myContextIndex + 1 }, async () => {
    var nextData = await this.setOptions(myData[0].children, options)
    if (myLevelIndex <= levels) {
      this.setState({ myLevelIndex: myLevelIndex + 1 }, async () => {
        await nextData.forEach(item =>
          this.addContext(item.children, options)
        )
      })
    }
    await nextData.forEach(item => myData[0].children.push(item))
  })
  return myData
}

setOptions = async (data, options) => {
  let arr = [...data]
  for (let i = 0; i < options; i++) {
    await arr.push(this.getDataNodeObject('Option', i + 1))
  }
  return arr
}

 getDataNodeObject = (name, index) => ({
   name: `${name + ' ' + index}`,
   children: [],
   index: index
 })
```

Is there a way to do it with all these conditions?

Answer (score 0):

You have an issue with the first code snippet: the `data` variable is an object, as it has curly brackets `{}`, but it doesn't have any keys. This will definitely cause a JavaScript runtime error.

Instead, I propose the following data model.

The root data object:

```js
const data = {
  name: "Context 1",
  option1: {}, // Inside the option1 property you can place an object that is identical to the data variable
  option2: {} // Inside the option2 property you can place an object that is identical to the data variable
}
```

Explanation: It looks like the `data`object you have to create is a recursive object. Recursive objects are objects that are contained inside themselves. For example, the `option1`key can contain an object that is identical to the `data`variable, like in the code snippet below. The same applies to the `option2` property.

```js
const data = {
  name: "Context 1",
  option1: {
    name: "Context 2",
    option1: {},
    option2: {}
  }
  option2: {} // Inside the option2 property you can place an object that is identical to the data variable
}
```

Comment: I've updated my object. I messed it up in the question while changing the variable names. And yeah its requires recursion but the conditions with it has hardened my job.